# Error when compiling Next.js app with intuit-oauth: the name `makeErrorCause` is defined multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am building a Next.js app and using the library `intuit-oauth`. I have used this library in Express.js apps without any issues, but for some reason when I try to use it in a Next.js app, I get the following error:

```
Error: 
  x the name `makeErrorCause` is defined multiple times
    ,-[/Users/alan/Repositories/balancer/balancer-next/node_modules/make-error-cause/dist/index.js:5:1]
  5 |     d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
  6 | };
  7 | var makeError = require('make-error');
  8 | function makeErrorCause(value, _super) {
    :          ^^^^^^^|^^^^^^
    :                 `-- previous definition of `makeErrorCause` here
  9 |     if (_super === void 0) { _super = makeErrorCause.BaseError; }
 10 |     return makeError(value, _super);
 11 | }
 12 | var makeErrorCause;
    :     ^^^^^^^|^^^^^^
    :            `-- `makeErrorCause` redefined here
 13 | (function (makeErrorCause) {
 14 |     var BaseError = (function (_super) {
 15 |         __extends(BaseError, _super);
    `----
```

When I drill down in to the `make-error-cause` library, the name `makeErrorCause` is indeed defined multiple times, this is straight from the index.js file:

```
function makeErrorCause(value, _super) {
    if (_super === void 0) { _super = makeErrorCause.BaseError; }
    return makeError(value, _super);
}
var makeErrorCause;
```

Not sure why they did that, but Next.js doesn't like it. The chain of dependencies is `intuit-oauth` -> `popsicle` -> `make-error` -> `make-error-cause`

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: did you find a resolution? still seeing the same thing

Comment: My solution was to stop using Intuit-oauth lol. I coded my own oauth solution and it was a bit of a pain but a good learning experience.